# How to add a unique auto inrement ID to yourvtable in the ODS when it's not present in the source with ssis

Tags: sql-server, ssis

In my staging area i have my source table "timesheet" from where i extract the name of the project to load it in my dimension "dim-project" in the ODS. But the problem is that i don't have the id of the project in my source. So i have to generate it in ssis.
And in my staging area i truncate my table before loading my data from my csv file.
And i do the same thing in my ODS i truncate the table "dim-project before loading it from my staging area.
So my question is how can i generate the id of my dimension project (that doesn't exist in my source)
and without facing a problem of the change of the id after applying truncate.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using an integer (ie: an identity) as an id, it won't work.  since you truncate both staging and ODS, you're not guaranteed to have the same id for the same row. you might want to use ROW_NUMBER() over (order by some field) to generate id, but there's always be some cases where a new project can be create with a name that will fit between two old project, then making the id to move.

Consider using hash of the business key(s) as id, it will meet your requirement.  if you can't modify the type of the id, you might want to cache the id base on a hash or business key(s)

Comment: I'm happy that you understood very well the situation that i'm facing. But i didn't understand the solution that you gave me. Can you explain it more (with details), please ?

Comment: it's a common problem with dimension, that why datavault do not use (anymore) sequence number and rely on hash value for ID.  SQL Server provides the hashbytes function to hash your business key.  Google for datavault tutorial, that will help you.